# Не работает событие keyup jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //show_index();

  $("#user_login").keyup(function() {
    console.log(this.value);
    $.ajax({
      url: "../config/functions.php?check_login=true&user_login=" + $('#user_login').val(),
      method: "GET"
    }).done(function(data) {
      if (data == 'unique') {
        console.log('failed_not_unique_login');
        $('#user_login').css('border', 'red solid 1px');
      } else {
        $('#user_login').css('border', 'black solid 1px');
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="user_login" type="text" />
```

И так вкратце, что должно происходить:

> **user** вводит ***ник*** при регистрации, он отправляется на сервере, обрабатывается и с сервера возвращается ответ.

Дело в том, что `keyup` почему то не отзывается, и никаких ошибок в консоли нет... Не могу понять в чем же все таки проблема.

Подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: Может потому что он находится внутри ready ? Попробуйте разделить одно от другого...

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME Нет дело не в этом (я проверил)

Comment: На странице нет элемента `input` с `id="user_login"`

Comment: @Igor Если бы небыло была бы ошибка в консоли + он точно есть

Comment: Зачем Вы говорите то, чего нет? Какая ошибка была бы?

Comment: Поддерживаю комментарий про отсутствие элемента. Посмотрите конечный DOM и попробуйте найти элемент с `id="user_login"`, нужно, чтобы он был один. А еще, Вы же в курсе, что у вас на каждое нажатие кнопки, когда активен инпут, будет улетать запрос - это не очень хорошо.

Comment: <input id="user_login" type="text" /> уникален для всей страницы?

Comment: На сервере происходит ошибка и `done` не вызывается. Добавьте еще `.fail(..)`

Comment: Эта строка `console.log(this.value);` вызывается?

Comment: @DenisBubnov Да, этого и добивался. Дело в том что если в консоли прописать запрос в ручную (а в нем используется value инпута), то все работает отлично запрос отправляется ошибок нет и сервер отвечает адекватно. Не срабатывает именно событие keyup, что очень странно...

Comment: @AntonShchyrov нет не вызывается ничего не срабатывает внутри keyup ибо он не зовется...А вот почему не зовется не ясно..

Comment: @KirillKorushkin Да он уникален.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил проблему так: повесил обработчик прямо в теге с помощью onkeyup

```
<input type='text' placeholder='nick' onkeyup='valid_nick_name()' />
```

Comment: Ну или как-то так ;)

Answer (score 1):

После всего написанного в комментах могу предположить, что элемент, на который вы вешаете keyup, динамический. Соответственно ready его не видит.
Вместо `$(document).ready` используйте анонимную функцию:

```
$(function(){
    // всё остальное
});
```

Или слушайте событие keyup по всему dom:

```
$('body').on('keyup', '#user_login', function () { ...
```